# Is it common to use a word "Conveyance"?

Tags: word-usage

I am currently working in New Zealand. Here, I was saying to somebody that "I don't have my own conveyance." Thus, I am relying on public transport to commute.

Is the conveyance an appropriate word here? I do know that back home in India, we use conveyance a lot to say about the transportation.Here, I meant that I don't have my own car/vehicle to commute.

Comment: What country's use are you asking about? In the US "conveyance" is very rare outside legal contexts, and even there it usually refers to the transfer of property from one person to another rather than to a transportation vehicle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm an Australian, but my uncle lives and works in New Zealand. He, like I, would say something along the lines of "I don't have my own car, and rely on public transport". Simple and direct.

As StoneyB said, 'conveyance' isn't a word commonly used outside of the legal/regulatory world.